# virtual directory in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, iis

I want to create virtual directory using vb.net. But while creating permission denied error occurs.If im manually creating virtual directory no error..
Pls advice any solution.

Comment: What edition of SQL Server 2005 did you install?

Answer (score 1):

You need the Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Express Edition Toolkit.  You can download it by clicking here: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=6511.

Hmm, that link no longer works... Try this one instead: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=19413